# While reading a DWORD from the Windows registry, I'm getting the pointer address and not the value as output

Tags: c++, windows, registry

So for a project I'm trying to read a Registry `DWORD`. I have written some code but I'm getting the pointers address as an output and not the value I'm looking for. Maybe someone can help me with that?

This it my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void registry_read(LPCTSTR subkey, LPCTSTR name, DWORD type)
{
    HKEY key;
    TCHAR value[255];
    DWORD value_length = 255;
    RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subkey, &key);
    RegQueryValueEx(key, name, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &value_length);
    RegCloseKey(key);
    cout << value << endl;
}

int main()
{
    registry_read(TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Valve\\Steam\\ActiveProcess"), TEXT("ActiveUser"), REG_DWORD);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried google/stackoverflow to look for my mistake but everything wont work because all results I found are for reg_sz and not for reg_dword.

Comment: I recommend the use of https://github.com/GiovanniDicanio/WinReg - It is a C++ wrappers around this low-level Win32 API. Instead of re-inventing the wheel. It is just an H file to include.

Answer (score 3):

When you read a `DWORD` value, your `value` should be of type `DWORD` (and the `value_length` should be the `sizeof DWORD`).

So the relevant lines will become:

```
DWORD type = REG_DWORD;
DWORD value;
DWORD value_length = sizeof(value);
RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey, &key);
RegQueryValueEx(key, name, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &value_length);
```

Notes:

1. You should also check the return value from the API calls ([`RegOpenKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeya), [`RegQueryValueEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexa)) to make sure they succeeded. They should return `ERROR_SUCCESS` upon success (and an [error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes) upon failure).
2. Since you need a diffrent variable type to read different types of values, the easiest would be to have separate functions (one for reading a `DWORD`, another for a string etc.).
3. Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).